# How to backup a folder with cloud like storage but offline?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, backup

I have a shared drive which is formatted as `ntfs`. When booting Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu, the drive mounds and I can read and write to it. The shared drive (`s/:`) is a third partition of the SSD.

This shared partition contains all of the files I created myself, and use day to day. These files are critical.

I am looking for a software that does the following:

1. Connect external drive to pc
2. Load up the `software`
3. Select the external drive partition I want files to be backed up to as `output`
4. Select the internal drive shared `s:/` drive as the `input`
5. Press go

When I press `go`, I would like for a scan to begin. This scan will determine the `tree` and `diff` differences between the input and output. If the input has been updated to the output before, then only files falling in one of the two categories is backed up:

- If a file has been modified since the last backup
- If a file did not exist during the last backup

If this is not the correct place to post this, please let me know. Thank you for your time.

TLDR; Looking for software to backup files in folders which will exclude backing up unmodified files since the last backup. Essentially what Dropbox does, but rather than go to cloud, go to an external drive when connected.

Comment: you can use the famous `rsync`. Read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync Example : `rsync --stats --delete -avzh /source/dir /dest/dir` be aware of the `--delete` option which may not match your need

Comment: @cmak.fr yeah that delete option looks intense. I'll read up on rsync, it looks like it may be what I'm looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the famous `rsync`. Read [rsync - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync).

Example:

```bsh
rsync --stats --delete -avzh /source/dir /dest/dir
```

Be aware of the `--delete` option matching mirroring needs (not archiving).

For syncing to/from a cloud storage, see https://rclone.org/

Comment: Do you think this post is a duplicate? I’m wondering if I should leave it up